# My Runnable for a custom View animation won't start.

Tags: android, runnable

I've been assigned to make a simple android app game in which the user controls a ball on the screen by tilting the phone. The app utilizes a custom view to draw all the objects and it uses a Runnable object to animate the ball. Note that x and y represent the ball's postilion, vx and vy represent the ball's velocity and fx and fy represent the forces being applied to it. ix and iy represent the phone's tilt; I set these two to dummy values in order to test the app without worrying about setting up the sensor manager for the time being :

```
private Runnable animator = new Runnable() {
        @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean needNewFrame = false;
        long now = AnimationUtils.currentAnimationTimeMillis();

        float dt = Math.min(now - lastTime, 50) / 1000f;

        fx = - alpha * vx + beta * ix;
        fy = - alpha * vy + beta * iy;

        vx = fx * dt;
        vy = fx * dt;

        if(x<xMin||x>xMax-ball_radius||y<yMin||y>yMax-ball_radius)
            bounce();

        x = x + vx * dt;
        y = y + vy * dt;

        lastTime = now;



        needNewFrame = true;

        postDelayed(this, 20);
        invalidate();
    }
};
```

I've set up the animator like so but it won't run. I tried calling post(animator) on the views initialization but that didn't work. How do I fix this?

Also, how do I set the ix and iy variables from the phone's tilt? From what I understand, the Sensor Manager is meant to be setup from an activity class.

[image: The Custom View for the game I'm trying to make]

Comment: try to use dynamically generated random values for the dummy values to test the effect

Comment: why to use post() / postDelayed() methods if you have ObjectAnimator / ValueAnimator which are designed to animate something???

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the animation does play successfully. It's just that the animation was playing very slowly.